# VS2013 Scaffolding Error when constructing view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting a curious error when attempting to generate a view via the 'Add View' dialog.  Simply leaving the dialog as is (ie creating view 'View') and hitting 'Add' yields the following error dialog:

> Error:  There was an error running the selected code generator:  'The Templates/PackageVersions5.0.1xml file is missing from the installed template folder.'

Which I'm afraid means little to me.  I've googled the xml file to no avail.

Not really sure where to go now - I'm unable to add views to my project via scaffolding (though I can of course just by 'adding a new item' and building it myself).

How can I track down the source of this error?

Comment: what was the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the rather unsatisfactory solution I arrived at was to create a clean project and import the project elements in, recreating the project from scratch.

I assume that some deep-configuration had become corrupted and I was unable to work out how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Posting here because I ran into the same "file is missing" issue with Visual Studio 2019 and PackageVersions5.2.6.xml.  This was one of the only pages I could find related to this scaffolding issue so I suspect others will find their way here too.

I found that upgrading the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" package via NuGet to 5.2.7 was not sufficient to fix the problem. I also had to upgrade "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" and its related packages to 5.2.7. The Add View option started working again afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you have same version of MVC nugget in all projects, if you only have one project then upgrade/downgrade MVC to different version then revert back to the version you require and issue will get fixed.

I just changed version from 5.2.3 back to 5.2.2 and then reverted back to 5.2.3 and all worked. It appears some file got messed up or and then was restored by this.

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue while using visual studio 2019 community edition, where I am able to create view using visual studio 2017.

After reading answers here, I tried upgrading Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc package, and it works for me.

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer. :)

Comment: In my case I also had to update Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi along with the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc nuget package. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when using a project from VS2013 in VS2015. In my case it was PackageVersions5.1.3.xml that was missing. 5.1.3 seems to be the version of MVC this project was using. I updated MVC to the latest (currently 5.2.3) and this solved the issue.

The XML file should exist in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem started after installing DevExpress to project. I found that DevExpress installation creates some DevExpress folders in `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions` but all necessary files for scaffolding lived in `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions`. I copied the content of extension folder from vs professional to enterprise restart Visual Studio and Scaffolding works again.